# Python | IOError Directory File Not Found

Tags: python, json, file, directory, ioerror

I am beyond confused on why it is not finding the file. Below is the code where the error is. Even though secrets.json is in the same directory as the script I am working on, I get this error: "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'secrets.json'"

Can someone help me on what to change here? I am an amateur coder and will really appreciate the help. Thanks!

I basically want this to open the secrets.json file and pull the key and secret key. I am using Sublime editor.

```
def get_secret(secret_file):
    """Grabs API key and secret from file and returns them"""

    with open(secret_file) as secrets:
        secrets_json = json.load(secrets)
        secrets.close()

    return str(secrets_json['key']), str(secrets_json['secret'])
# setup api
key, secret = get_secret("secrets.json")
api = exchange(key, secret)
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Maybe the working directory is not the same as your source directory. Simply try an absolute path.

Comment: Yes. Provide the FULL path, and also remove the redundant `secrets.close()`.

Comment: Wow that was a quick fix. Thank you kindly!